# Specify or in regular expression in node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

This is the code:

```
// Only gzip javascript files:
gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', { matchType: /javascript/ })
```

This is the node.js module: https://github.com/nateps/connect-gzip

It signifies compression only for javascript files. How can I specify compression for files either javascript or css? since I want to enable compression for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`|` (or) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) in the provided regular expression to match on either:

```
gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', { matchType: /javascript|css/ })
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', { matchType: /javascript/ })
```

on:

```
gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', { matchType: /javascript|css/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', { matchType: /javascript|CSS|HTML|WHATEVER/ })
```